# Is there a way to forbid a function to be called more than one time?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm making a terminal app just to increase my OOP skills. I have this `RunApplication()`function and `LoginCustomer()`function to make a customer log in to the application.

This code is my `RunApplication`function:

```
void RunApplication(){
    while (key!='q'){
    printUI();
    std::cin >> key;
    if (key == '1'){
        LoginCustomer();
    } 
    ..... // There are many other if statements but not included here since there are many and irrelevant.
```

and this is my `LoginCustomer`function:

```
void LoginCustomer(){
    std::cout << "***************************" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1 ----> Show Available Cars" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2 ----> Show Available Motors" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "3 ----> Show Available Trucks" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "always 'l'  ----> Logout" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "always 'q'  ----> Exit" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "***************************" << std::endl;    
    std::cin >> key;
    if (key == 'l') //if you want to go back main page which was loaded into terminal with RunApplication() 
        return;
    else if(key == 'q')
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
        return; // What if I just call RunApplication() here again instead a simple return, wouldn't program be the most inefficient program ?
    else if(key == 'q')
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

My question is can I forbid a function to be called more than one time in a program(or main) ? Because if you think about it, in the  `LoginCustomer` If you press "l" it gets you to the main page by simply ending the `LoginCustomer()`using `return`command. But what if I would just use `RunApplication()`there again instead of `return`command wouldn't be there a inefficiency in program ? So I was thinking is there any `keyword`to forbid a function to be called more than one time ?

Comment: c++ would not prevent you from writing inefficient code (nor any language I know)

Comment: and recursion is pretty often used technique

Comment: @appleapple I know recursion is a pretty often used technique but with the wrong usage of it your code  becomes the most inefficient code in the world :) I

Comment: Of course you can forbid it (`/* don't call this twice */`).  I guess the question is whether you can get the language to enforce that...

Comment: It seems that what you actually want is that `RunApplication()` never (indirectly) call itself, rather than it being called only once per process.  It's quite reasonable, for example, that your unit tests should be able to exercise the function several times with different inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is can I forbid a function to be called more than one time in a program(or main) ?

You can use local `static` variables to have a guarantee that the code is called only once.

Example:

```
struct FunctionObject
{
    FunctionObject()
    {   
        std::cout << "I will be called only once" << std::endl;
    }   
};

void Do()
{
    static FunctionObject fo; 
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << "First" << std::endl;
    Do();
    std::cout << "Second" << std::endl;
    Do();
}
```

But for your UI example I would prefer a design with simple state machine which take care that states can only be activated in a given order.

> I'm making a terminal app just to increase my OOP skills.

Your example code did not have any object nor any OOP design. Maybe you have some classes/objects elsewhere, but I can't see any OOP design in your code.

Comment: And why not the function Do can be called several times?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow  Because it is an example! You can do the same in main and create the object there...

Comment: @Klaus Thanks for your answer. I didn't share any OOP parts of my program.  I guess I should just remove the oop tag.

Comment: @AliZiyaÇEVİK: If you want to say "thanks" use the "upvote" to pay. If the answer solves your problem, accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @Klaus Your example does not make a sense. Just append the function with these statements      static size_t n;
    std::cout <<"I'm called " << ++n << " time(s)\n";

Comment: @Klaus I haven't tried it yet. Once I try and it works, no worries I will accept it :)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The code in function object is called only once, the code in Do is called multiple times. OP asks how to prevent code to be called multiple times. The code in FunctionObject constructor is called only once which is the expected behaviour. No idea what should be "no sense".

Comment: @Klaus  It does not look like a function call because the user can create several objects of the structure type in his code.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I never told someone that it should look like a function call. It simply uses the c++ implementation to guarantee that a part of code is executed once. This is a bit more efficient than writing a own guard as static var which will generate 2 variables instead of one. All programming languages will offer hundreds of possible solutions for simple problems. My example is exactly one solution which (hopefully) fulfill the given requirement: Call the code only once.  OOP design uses often objects to get code called, so why you argue about not using a function call?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: See the example of Mike: Here you have two variables in use. One var protectes the code running over the init function for iCount and iCount itself is another var. In addition he needs another if/else clause. This is the hand crafted version which is much less efficient but maybe easier to read. The logic is the same: Use a variable to store if the code was called.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::call_once`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once

```
static std::once_flag flag;
std::call_once(flag, []{
    //code here..
});
```

Comment: Very inefficient typically. All parms to func will be copied before execution and we have two variables in use. One var protects flag for multiple init and flag itself. And as it is made for used in threading context, implementation uses some additional guards against race conditions between different threads.

Comment: @Klaus; Documentation says parameters aren’t copied or moved. OP didn’t specify whether they need thread safety or not, I’m just supplying an alternative answer to the ones listed.

Comment: There is an defect report: https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2442. My understanding is, that current implementations/standard is defined in that way, that parameter copy takes place. Maybe it is solved in the meantime, but current doc still reports it as a bug.

Comment: @Klaus; I can't reproduce the bug: https://ideone.com/sY4Doa Tested on clang 12, gcc 10, and VS2019. Also checked on `godbolt`: https://godbolt.org/z/hdrEMj17j and with -O3: https://godbolt.org/z/ashK1Ysbz

If you change the argument to `Foo&&` it will show an error of `std::__invoke(std::forward<_Callable>)` so seems correct to me that it forwards perfectly. Changing it to `Foo` will cause a copy as expected. `Foo&` no copy, `const Foo&` no copy, etc..

Comment: Nice to hear! So only the doc which still tell us, that there is a bug is a bug :-) Thanks for testing! Maybe you give cppreference a hint? But I did not know how is really tracking the DRs. If the DR is still open... I have no idea whats best :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Local variables are stored and created on the stack. Static local variables are constant and remain between calls so:

```
bool my_one_off_function ()
{
    static int iCount = 0;    //  static only intialized at start of program

    if  (! iCount++)          //  First time only will be zero
    {
        do_first_call_stuff ();
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Alternatively, in your specific case, when the login request is received, you could just check if the login credentials already exist before calling the login function. This would be the more "elegant" solution because it allows logout etc.

Comment: probably slightly pedantic, but iCount can/will eventually roll over. If you made it a bool and then set it false inside the if (or increment the int) then it would be safe to call this function as many times as you want :)

Comment: Yeah, I know. I just wanted to make the code as simple as possible for the demonstration and I figured anyone who logs in  2 billion times without restarting their application probably had it coming.